# Weird Arabic notification on login

Tags: 14.04, login, notification, calendar, arabic

I don't speak Arabic and neither have I installed anything related to Arabic,
but on login I get this strange notification:

[image]

What could be the cause and how do I get rid of it? (Also, what does it say?)

Thanks

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you running?

Comment: @Mitch Oh, I'm running 14.04 x64 - I think it has something to do with the calendar, since today is July 16th and it mentions 2014/16 and 1435/18 for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a program called Hijri Applet.  Since you don't know how it happened, you can remove it using Ubuntu Software Center.

[image]

Comment: That did the trick, thank you. I'm still rather curious as to what it had to say and how it got there, though...